# How to end the session after logging out in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfc

I'm using CFML for my application. I need help with developing a logout operation that destroys a session. For now, on the logout link I'm calling the login page but when the BACK Button on the browser is clicked the user is still logged in.

```
<!---LoginForm.cfm>--->

<!---Handle the logout--->

<cfif structKeyExists(URL,'logout')>
    <cfset createObject("component",'authenticationService').doLogout() />
</cfif>
<!---Form processing begins here--->
<cfif structkeyExists(form,'submitLogin')>
    <!---Create an instane of the authenticate service component--->
    <cfset authenticationService=createObject("component",'authenticationService') />
    <!---Server side data validation--->
    <cfset aErrorMessages=authenticationService.validateUser(form.userEmail,form.userPassword)>
    <cfif ArrayisEmpty(aErrorMessages)>
        <!---Proceed to the login procedure --->
        <cfset isUserLoggedIn=authenticationService.doLogin(form.userEmail,form.userPassword) >
    </cfif>
</cfif>
<!---Form processing ends here--->
<cfform>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <cfif structKeyExists(variables,'aErrorMessages') AND NOT  ArrayIsEmpty(aErrorMessages)>
        <cfoutput>
        <cfloop array="#aErrorMessages#" index="message" >
            <p >#message#</p>
        </cfloop>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfif> 
    <cfif structKeyExists(variables,'isUserLoggedIn') AND isUserLoggedIn EQ false>
        <p class="errorMessage">User not found.Please try again!</p>
    </cfif>
    <cfif structKeyExists(session,'stLoggedInUser')>
        <!---display a welcome message--->
        <p><cfoutput>Welcome #session.stLoggedInUser.userFirstName# </cfoutput>
        <p><a href='#'>My profile</a><a href="LoginForm.cfm?logout">Logout</a></p>
    <cfelse>
        <dl>
        <dt>
            <label for="userEmail">Email address</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <cfinput type="email" name="userEmail" required="true" >
        </dd>
        <dt>
            <label for="userEmail">Password</label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <cfinput type="password" name="userPassword" required="true" >
        </dd>
        </dl>
        <cfinput type="submit" name="submitLogin" value="Login" />
        </fieldset>
    </cfif>
</cfform>
<cfdump var="#session#">


<!---authenticationService.cfc--->
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="validateUser" access="public" output="false" returntype="array">
        <cfargument name="userEmail" type="string" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="userPassword" type="string" required="true" />
        <cfset var aErrorMessages=ArrayNew(1) />
        <!---Validate the email--->
        <cfif NOT isValid('email',arguments.userEmail)>
            <cfset arrayAppend(aErrorMessages,'Please,provide a valid email address') />
        </cfif>
        <!---Validating the Password--->
        <cfif arguments.userPassword EQ ''>
            <cfset arrayAppend(aErrorMessages,'Please, provide a password') />
        </cfif>
        <cfreturn aErrorMessages />
    </cffunction>
    <!---doLogin() Method--->
    <cffunction name="doLogin" access="public" output="false" returntype="boolean">
        <cfargument name="userEmail" type="string" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="userPassword" type="string" required="true" />
        <!---create the isUserLoggedIn variable--->
        <cfset var isUserLoggedIn=false />
        <!---get the user data from the database--->
        <cfquery datasource="myapp" name="getInfo">
            select * from Info 
            where emailid='#form.userEmail#' and password='#form.userPassword#'
        </cfquery>
        <!---Check if the query returns one and only one user--->
        <cfif getInfo.recordcount eq 1 >
            <!--- log the user in --->
            <cflogin>
                <cfloginuser name="#getInfo.username#" password="#getInfo.password#" roles="#getInfo.role#">
            </cflogin>
            <!--- save user data in session scope --->
            <cfset session.stLoggedInUser={'userFirstName'=getInfo.username} />
            <!---change the isUserLoggedIn variable to true--->
            <cfset var isUserLoggedIn=true />
        </cfif>
        <!---return the isUserLoggedIn variable --->
        <cfreturn isUserLoggedIn />
    </cffunction>
    <!---doLogout() Method--->
    <cffunction name="doLogout" access="public" output="false" returntype="any">
        <!---delete user from session scope--->
        <cfset structDelete(session,'stLoggedInUser') />
        <!---log the user out--->
        <cflogout />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: [Implementing user security is fairly well documented here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/securing-applications/implementing-user-security.html). A couple of other comments on the query in your code. Specifically this line `where emailid='#form.userEmail#' and password='#form.userPassword#'`. Do not store passwords in clear text. Hash them and then store them. Do not directly use `form` variables in your queries. This opens your application to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries and validate ALL information that is passed

Comment: @Miguel-F That's old text that still recommends using a plaintext password. It's a good explanation of CF's login features, but the documented implementation has some very bad practices. I wish Adobe would update that page to show some better practices. :-/

Comment: @Madhu, take a look at https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.md or anything at https://www.petefreitag.com. If you are going to have security in your application, it's important to do it well and completely.

Comment: But probably the most important thing to remember re: logins is that only the user should ever be able to know the entered password. Use some sort of secure hashing algorithm to change the password before inserting in the db, then use the same algorithm to check it before logging them in. You can use `cfloginuser` to do the login, but run the password through your algorithm before passing the value to the function. Though that may be a case where it's better to roll your own login.

Comment: @Miguel-F I agree. It's a demo page, so the password is in decrypted form...the only thing I want is to end session...please share solutions if uh have any

Comment: @Shawn it's just an sample application only designed to learn sessions...the thing is even after logging out the user can see the data on clicking back button...I want to end the session completely... If I get a solution for sessions, I gonna follow this code in my original application where passwords were encrypted/Hashed.

Comment: Re: the original question, if you want to kill a session, you can either `structClear("session")` (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structclear.html) or if not using J2EE sessions `sessionInvalidate()` (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/sessioninvalidate.html). If you're using `cflogin` functionality, you can use `cflogout` (https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cflogout.html).

Comment: Thank you @Shawn, I will try using structClear("session"). I'm not using J2EE.

Comment: What is the difference between clearing the session and deleting the session?

Comment: Although, you may not be talking about session data if you're also talking about pressing the Back Button. You may be dealing with a browser's cache.

Comment: `structClear("session")` wipes the entire `session` struct. `structDelete(session,'stLoggedInUser')` deletes the `stLoggedInUser` key from the `session` struct.

Comment: You can use sessionRotate() after clearing the session, which will give you a new session ID, but it will not call onSessionStart(). That’s the closest thing to “starting a new session”. Remember, just because the user logged out doesn’t mean a new session is needed. You could simply clear the session data, or the parts of the session that reference the user.

Comment: <script type = "text/javascript" > function preventBack() { window.history.forward(1); } setTimeout("preventBack()", 0); window.onunload = function () { null }; </script>

                                                          But back button is completly disabled and the data is buffering.  But, I dont want to disable back button functionality when user   decides to logout it should redirect to signup page or Google home page...The only thing is after user logged out he shouldn't enable to access his data by clicking back button or reloading the page...he should see the data only after log

Comment: @Madhu I wouldn't overly rely on JavaScript to prevent people from pushing a Back button. Or really any other button. JS is more of a convenience thing than a security thing. It's easy to get around for someone that wants to.

Comment: It should be perfectly fine for a user to hit the back button... they won't be logged in anymore, but they would be able to see what they used to be able to see when they were. If they did something on a previous page that required them to be logged in, they wouldn't be, so they would get a 403 error (or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the back button after logout, the situation being that someone could log off and walk away from their computer without closing the browser or locking it. Then anyone else could go back on their browser and view the data they had been viewing before logging out.

We solved this for a financial application by implementing a `Pragma: no-cache` header on every page request. This forces requests to the page to reload from the server, not just load what's in the browser's cache. This means the back button will request the previous URL from the server, which will check session and kick you to your logged out landing page.

It will throw off some users who are used to navigating your site a certain way, but it will make it much more secure.